# Is an EF query's null check performed on the db or webserver?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF and Sql Server (CE). I'm trying to ensure as much as possible is run on the db. Consider this:

```
var data =
  getSomeEntities()
  .OrderBy(a => a.Date)
  .Select(a => new {
    Id    = a.Id,
    Name  = a.Name,
    Ref   = a.CustomerProfile != null ? a.CustomerProfile.Ref : null,     // ???
    Email = a.Email
  })
  .ToList();
```

Is the null check (the line marked with "???") executed on the db, or is materialized first and performed on the web server?

<del>Also, I've noticed some of my code doesn't even perform that null check and works, and in some places if I don't do it then it throws. I wonder if it's even necessary?</del>

Comment: The second part of your question is too vague to answer, as you haven't given any code to explain. (You should provide two pieces of code, one of which works and one of which throws an exception... then we could compare them.)

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right of course, but in theory there is no special proxy magic going on to such properties? If it's nullable then I always need to check for null?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing with them - which we can't tell as you haven't shown the code. I don't know what you mean by "special proxy magic" as again, *we have no context*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay I'll handle that in another question. I was referring to the EF proxy class mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's performed in the database - if you add appropriate logging, you should see the appropriate SQL to get the right result.

In C# 6 you can just use

```
Ref = a.CustomerProfile?.Ref
```